# Dynamically Generate UITableViews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

Ok I am making a call to a web service to get policies back. The user can have multiple policies, and these policies are to have there own table (Please note not there own section in a table). These tables can have an unknown number of rows in them all depending on the number of amendments to the policy plus the policy itself. So I need to dynamically generate the tables for this onto a UIScrollView. Does anyone know how I can do this? If you don't understand me then please ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create UITableViews programmatically with

```
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
```

then set the view controller to be the delegate and data source of the table view:

```
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
```

and add the table view to your scroll view like such:

```
tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 500); //use whatever frame you want here
[self.scrollView addSubview:tableView];
```

and in order to keep track of the table views, you can use the tag associated with each one. These are probably best defined as constants at the top of your .m file. You can name them appropriately so you know what policy the table view is supposed to be for. For example, at the top of your .m file:

```
#define kFirstPolicyTableViewTag 1
```

and then when creating the table view:

```
tableView.tag = kFirstPolicyTableViewTag;
```

then, when dealing with any of the delegate or data source methods, check the tag so you know which one you are dealing with. For example:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    switch (tableView.tag) {
        case kFirstPolicyTableViewTag: {
            //return the number of rows for that tag
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you +1 has it this has helped

Answer (score 1):

I recommend creating a sectioned table view. So you can load policies in each section. And you can give some section header on each section to give more information.

Comment: I would like to do it this way as it is a lot easier but I have been instructed to do it the other way. Clients being a pain.

Answer (score 1):

The textbook approach for N policies, each with M amendments (both N and M arbitrary and potentially large) is UINavigationController with a table of policies at the root level.  Selecting a row (a policy) pushes to a policy detail view controller that contains a table of amendments for that policy.

Comment: Thanks +1. This basically the way I was doing it but because the client has now passed on details of how they want it to work I have had to change it.