# Dynamically setting the height and position of dynamically generated UITableviews?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

Right first of I would like to thank everyone for helping me out on the [Dynamically Generate UITableViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892000/dynamically-generate-uitableviews/9892385#9892385). But I need to expand the question a bit to a new problem that i have found. Whilst I can now generate the table dynamically I need to know how to set the height of the tables dynamically based on how many rows there will be. If you read the thread above I basically have to generate x tables based on how many policies the user has but that table can have x amount of rows in it not always or all being the same amount. How can I do this so that the next table will start off at the correct part of the view after the table that is above it? So that they are not overlapping?

Please if I have asked this wrong and you do not understand please ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you have the number of rows in each table available, then it isn't too difficult.

I'm assuming you have your table views all in an array for easy management.

You'd simply have to loop through the array while keeping a counter for position then size the table views based on the counter.

```
CGFloat currentYPosition = 0;

for (UITableView *tableView in allTableViews) {
    CGRect frame = tableView.frame;

    CGFloat height = tableView.rowHeight * numberOfRowsInTableView;

    frame.origin.y = currentYPosition;
    frame.size.height = height;

    tableView.frame = frame;

    currentYPosition += height;
}
```

For the height variable, you can add any other extras that you might have (table view header, footer, etc.)

Comment: I was in the middle of entering something just like this. As long as he can get the number of policies from his web service and appropriately create the tableViews and store them in said array, this looks good